# How do you read a text file and make every 4 words all capital print to the console window?

Tags: java

I try to print every 4 words of my text file with capital letter in console, but this code prints all of my file capital and I can't find out why?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("players.txt"));
            int count = 0;
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String line = sc.next();
                String[] elements = line.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    if (i/3 == 0){
                        System.out.println(elements[i].toUpperCase());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(elements[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The number of capital letters are: " + count);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two things going wrong:

a)
the line `String[] elements = line.split(" ");` does not split the line at every word. The way you use the `Scanner` already splits them (because the `Scanner`'s default delimeter is a space), meaning that your `line` variable always only contains one word.

Fix this by using `sc.useDelimeter("\n");` before the `while(sc.hasNext())` loop.

b)
replace

```
if(i/3 == 0){
```

with

```
if(i%4 == 0){ //modulo division
```

Comment: *"Fix this by using `sc.useDelimeter("\n");` before the `while(sc.hasNext())` loop."* Well, it would be way better/easier to use `String line = sc.nextLine();`, don't you think? :)

Comment: @Tom true, you could also that :D

Answer (score 0):

here is complete code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("players.txt"));
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] elements = line.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(elements[i].toUpperCase());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(elements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of capital letters are: " + count);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

For the file with content: w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10 w11 w12
output will be:
w1
w2
w3
W4
w5
w6
w7
W8
w9
w10
w11
W12